# boton con accion incluida

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Tengo una pagina donde muestro los registros almacenados en la base de datos, y en ese listado tengo dos link, uno para nuevos registros que me lleva a la pagina del formulario:

```
<a href="<?= base_url(); ?>/welcome/registro/nuevo" class="link-success">Nuevo_registro<i class="fas user-edit" ></i></a>
```

Y otro que me debe de llevar a la misma pagina del formulario pero para editar, es el siguiente:

```
<a href="<?= base_url(); ?>/welcome/registro/editar"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></a>
```

Como pueden ver en el `href` le coloco al final de la url el valor, si es un nuevo registro o voy a editar un registro, pero no se como obtener ese ultimo valor (nuevo, editar) en el controlador para alli segun el caso mostrar el formulario en blanco o mostrar los datos del registro a editar .

Trabajo con codeigniter version 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu controlador a tu funcion de registro puedes agregar un parámetro tal como:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function registro($accion)
    {
        if($accion == 'nuevo'){
            # code
        }else if($accion == 'editar'){
            # code
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

El listado en el que colocas esos dos links viene de una tabla de tu base de datos. Al recuperar la información también debes haber recuperado el valor de la clave primaria de esa tabla (generalmente llamada 'id'). Digamos que tu información está en la variable $*datos*. Entonces al link para editar le colocas al final el valor del id (que identifica el registro que vas a editar):

```
<a href="<?= base_url(); ?>/welcome/registro/editar/<?php echo $datos['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></a>
```

*Edición para ampliar:*

En el controlador:

```
protected $clase;
public function editar($id) {
    $clase = $this->clase->where('id', $id)->first();
    $data = ['titulo' => 'Editar', 'datos' => $clase];
    // muestras la vista aqui
}
```

*Clase* sería el nombre de tu objeto (productos, clientes, etc.). En el controlador también debes hacer referencia al modelo.

Comment: claro pero como recibo ese valor adicional en el controlador? por que la accion la recibo, deberia colocar otra variable en la funcion del controlador?

Comment: La variable $id es el valor que se recibe desde el formulario